# Is there a limit on how much is customizable on WordPress?

Tags: customization, e-commerce

I recently started a project in which I need to make some custom features to achieve the following goals from the client:

> A musician which needs to show his work, publish some articles, and sell access to online tutorials and CD's/DVD's.

- An e-commerce, where the user can buy online tutorials.
  ** When the payment is done, I need to give access to the tutorial section so the user can watch the videos via streaming
  ** Today he already has an online shop, but it only sells CD's and DVD's, which is a lot simpler and doesn't involve anything but only notifying him about the purchases (WooCommerce)
- Some common website features (portfolio, discuss area, articles) in a responsive and clean layout

What makes me a little bit worried about the possibility of doing this is that the site is using WordPress.

I'm new to this tool, and I saw that I'm limited to plugins and themes to make my job. It is a lot intuitive and easy to end-user's control because of the administrative panel.

To get my question better structured:

- How limited I am when working in WordPress? In terms of front end customization (JS, CSS, HTML) and "back-end" customization (implement a new feature on the site, as said about the "tutorial shop" section)
- Can I achieve that goals easily with WordPress features? I don't know **which** tools I actually depend to achieve that.
- I was thinking about re-developing it in ASP.NET, but I don't know if it will take a lot of extra time and become a lot more complex by implementing the online shop and the administrative features that WordPress already has. The solution needs to keep itself still easy to deal with.

Comment: Anything can be done with wordpress. Is it the best tool for you and for your project? it depends on your specific knowledge and abilities and no one will be able to answer it for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *How limited am I when working in WordPress? In terms of front end customization (JS, CSS, HTML) and "back-end" customization (implement a new feature on the site, as said about the "tutorial shop" section)*

You're only as limited with your knowledge of WordPress and programming. You can make changes to the frontend or backend by [using](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) or [creating](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) your own plugin(s). The same goes for [creating your own theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) or using a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to further modify an existing theme.

> *Can I achieve that goals easily with WordPress features? I don't know which tools I actually depend to achieve that.*

With some research on [setting up WordPress as an ecommerce](https://www.google.com/#q=wordpress+ecommerce), yes. There are plenty of plugins and tutorials to turn WordPress into an online shop. Just a matter of choosing the one that's right for you.